# Understanding of Histogram-of-Oriented-Gradients

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, local-features, feature-extraction

I am learning about HOG and I understand it from [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/). A well-explained page with an example. I am not understanding this concept that how it works

> A 16×16 block has 4 histograms which can be concatenated to form a 36
>   x 1 element vector and it can be normalized just the way a 3×1 vector
>   is normalized.

How this **36*1** came and how we calculated it? and is it compulsory that we always need 9 bin vector? Is it a fixed size for HOG?

came?

Answer (score 1):

> How this 36*1 came and how we calculated it?

HOG is an algorithm which:

- works on a portion of the image, called "detection window";
- divides the "detection window" in a certain number of cells;
- associates an histogram (of oriented gradients) to each cell.
  Each histogram has N orientation bins. WLOG, here, we'll consider N=9);
- "Normalization step" (to make histogram values not affected by lighting 
  variations): it creates blocks (where each block is made up of 4 cells 
  (2x2)), and it overlaps them;
- creates a vector for each block (so, **4 cells x 9 orientation = 36 components for block**)
- creates a final vector, associated to the overall "detection window";
- the final vector is passed to an SVM classifier.

At each iterations, the "detection window" scans the whole original image, and the HOG algorithm is applied at each scan.

> and is it compulsory that we always need 9 bin vector? Is it a fixed size for HOG?

No, the usage of 9 orientation bins for each histogram is not mandatory; it's only a trade-off to which the authors came through tests, as stated by MimSaad.

In [this paper](https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf), it is explained that increasing the number of orientation bins improves performance significantly up to about 9 bins; beyond this value, perfomance doesn't improve considerably.
Figure 4b shows this result.

Answer (score 0):

Each histogram has 9 orientation bins and 4 histograms are concatenated hence 36 bins.
I am not sure about HOG, but I assume alike SIFT algorithm, the original authors come up with trial and error for 9 bins, for trade off between accuracy and computational cost. More bins results in more distinguishable dense feature points but of course is computationally more complex.